# What does "educated" mean in "educated guess"?

Tags: meaning

> Make an educated guess.

What is the meaning of *educated* in the sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An *educated guess* is a guess in which you take into account factors which might affect the outcome using reason. It is a term used to clarify that a guess is not one which is made “off the top of your head”—that is, guessing the first possibility that comes to mind—but rather one which, although it is still a guess, is generated by considering multiple possibilities and selecting the one thought most likely by considering those factors that a reasonable person might assume will affect the outcome.

Comment: Does _educated_ in _educated guess_ have the same/similar meaning of _reasoned_?

Comment: Reasoned comes into it, but I'd say *informed* is a better substitute, if it's a substitute you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative synonym: informed (and ill-informed, perhaps, as an autonym).

Comment: perhaps you meant "antonym"?

Answer (score 2):

When I use this expression, I mean a guess that is informed by experience and knowledge not readily apparent to the average person, rather than based on average person's information base plus some thought.

Comment: I agree - knowledge, probably specialist knowledge, is the key ingredient, not thought.

Answer (score 1):

Synonym: reasoned. Antonym: wild.